# Filtering to avoid need to overuse Skip in Triage, Low Quality Posts, et al

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

When I review posts in the Triage, Low Quality Posts or some of the other related review queues, I find that I am simply clicking <kbd>Skip</kbd>, because I do not know enough about the subject at hand to make a distinction of whether the post was a valid or inadequate question.

OPs supply code, often some sample data (depending on the subject) and a narrative that to my mind describes their situation. While I do not understand the specifics, I thought it was valid yet it was tagged into the review queue by someone familiar with the subject so I am reviewing it. I hit <kbd>Skip</kbd> after reviewing the post from top to bottom, but without completely educating myself on the subject. There goes anywhere from 2-6 minutes of my life.

> Case in point: I skipped [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7498364), because I could not see ANYTHING wrong with it. I was wrong to skip it. I should have said nothing was wrong, but I simply did not have enough expertise in the subject to justify being part of an override to all of the votes that sent it to review.

I do feel that there should be a way to filter these review categories in order that our 'expertise' can be directed toward the matters that we are familiar with. I'm tired of wasting my time reviewing something I cannot make an informed decision upon. Naive democracy be damned; let those who know the subject make the decisions.

While I do not have access to the full Stack Overflow statistics matrix, I would bet [dollars to donuts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bet_dollars_to_donuts) (I'm old, but that used to be a valid pop-culture <s>colloquialism</s> meme) that much time is lost by dedicated 'reviewers' from not being able to 'review' a question properly. They put in the time and effort to read through a post, but they come to a standstill when trying to make an intelligent, informed decision.

This is a waste of time and effort from the volunteers that should be addressed. Being able to filter the Triage, Low Quality (and possibly other) queues that are reviewed would cut this wasteful expenditure down considerably. After that, it may only be one's own level of expertise in a subject that allows them to make the decision to click a button and move on to the next.

I will admit to having learned a few things reviewing posts that did not have anything to do with my 'sandbox', and I have *right-click-Open-In-New-Tab* in order to attempt an answer at a few. My point is that the overall majority of my time reviewing these two review queue categories in particular is wasted, and I would like the option to opt-in to a filtered queue.

FWIW, I believe that more than a few bad click choices have been made based upon an unfamiliarity with the subject matter at hand, but I'll also wager that a few politicians are in office for the same reason.

<sub>It's possible I should just stick with the <kbd>Close</kbd> votes in my own sandbox. There never seems to be a shortage of those.</sub>

Comment: Most queues allow you to filter by tags, except for Triage (I believe that will be implemented in the future).

Comment: Well, you're doing it right.  These queues are however not normally big enough to let SE group by [tag], other than the Close queue.  If this feels like a big drain on your free time without much to show for it then rest assured that you're not the only SO user that feels that way.  Answering questions is the more satisfying and productive activity.

Comment: @HansPassant - An optional filter for this on a cookie (or JSON) would cost much less than the scripts we already openly accept (and enjoy!). For those that choose to accept it, all the more wiser or not as the case may be.

Comment: The people who put the questions into H&I don't necessarily know anything about the topic either.

Comment: I won't examine the Triage queue again until it has a filter.

Comment: Use the middle button on your mouse to _Open-In-New-Tab_ instead of using the right click menu.

Comment: I'd like to see at least soft-filtering, where it tries to match you up with your tag and only gives you something random if there's nothing left for the tag.

Comment: and it is still not implemented. Thus i keep on skip using triage at all.