# Is there a way to Triage without spending most of my time skipping unfamiliar technology?

Tags: discussion, triage

I just did a Triage session, and ended up hitting the Skip button 19 out of 20 times because the questions were specific to languages or products that were unfamiliar to me.  This feels like a waste of time.

Is there a better way?

The first (but not very good) strategy that jumps to mind is for Triage to let me choose a set of tags, and restrict my triaging to questions that have at least one of my chosen tags.  But I think that would cause more harm than good, because it wouldn't really let me express the criteria that make me hit 'Skip': that is, it would filter out many questions that I am capable and happy to triage, and/or it would still present me with many questions specific to (and tagged with) unfamiliar languages in addition to my chosen set.

It seems to me what I really want is to be able to say "Skip, and don't ask me about any more questions tagged with [this language/product that I don't know and am not going to learn any time soon]".

Would that work?  Would it be feasible?  Any other bright ideas?

Comment: You're not there to evaluate the technical merits of the question in Triage.  While there will be times that you won't understand the scope of a question, be able to tell if it's answerable, etc. due to not knowing the subject matter, quite often it will be quite clear (one way or the other) whether it's a question that belongs on this site even if it's not a subject matter you're an expert in.

Comment: @Servy, I understand that concept, but I found it not to be applicable 19 out of 20 times just now.  I was unable to make head or tail of the question because of the unfamiliar language.  Really, this happened.

Comment: @Servy to know whenever or not a question is about programming, you need to have knowledge about *what programming is*! If the text you are reading looks like a joke but it's really LOLCODE, well, you would flag as off topic when actually it isn't.

Comment: @Braiam Between the tags on the question and the information in the question outside of just the code (and also the code in the question being properly formatted as code, telling you something's up) should, at a minimum,  give you enough information to know that the question is *so* far out of your depth that you can't judge it at all.  Again, I'm not saying you don't *ever* need to have subject matter expertise to determine if a question merits closure, just that you often don't.

Comment: I find there are a lot of posts in triage that are so obviously bad that I can tell you if something is wrong with the post and I'll flag it even if I know práctically nothing about the language, however I am a lot more unsure to say everything is all right when it's technology I don't know well because something might look ok that's not, so I tend to skip those.

Comment: "oh hai, why i get error stupid error my code in algol bad helpp i dleted my code cause bad cause error help" <- bad question even if you have never heard of the language.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yes, I get it.  19 out of 20 today were not that obvious.   When I don't know the language/product, it's often difficult to tell the difference between jargon and gibberish, and it seems like more and more of the questions I've tried to review lately have fallen into that category... today almost all of them.  Has something changed lately?  Seems like it wasn't like this a year or two ago when I started Triaging.

Comment: Can you give some examples?  [mcve] style?

Comment: There are more and more corner case technologies as time grow, there is two skills discussed here : Being able to recognize a technologie enough to judge it, and being able to recognize a good question whatever the technologie is. So, you'r saying that you could not recognize the technologie neither the quality of the question ? 19 out of 20 ? What exactly is your range of knowledge ? Maybe there is just not many question about what you know ?

Comment: I feel like it would be nice to have the option to only triage questions that match a certain set of tags

Comment: @AntoinePelletier in answer to your question of what exactly is my range of knowledge-- the 74 tags on my [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2552290/don-hatch?tab=tags) looks pretty representative. In general I would probably be comfortable Triaging most questions whose tags are *only* from that list, and/or aren't specific to some other very language-or-product-specific tag.

Comment: @DanField I'll try to gather some examples.  Review queue is empty at this moment.

Comment: I don't understand why people feel it necessary to argue with someone's experience.  If a UI is frustrating people won't use it. Telling them they are just not working hard enough (or worse just not clever or careful enough) to really understand what they are supposed to do is just not helpful. Listen to their experience and accept that it is real.

Comment: [Review triage questions accordingly to my favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280773). [Why is there no filter in triage review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297317) [Filtering to avoid need to overuse Skip in Triage, Low Quality Posts, et al](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288874).

Comment: Many of the questions I was asked to review just now only contained tags from my ignore list or that weren't on either my accept or ignore lists.  Also, the review instructions say we are to skip when we aren't sure ... and often I wasn't sure if the info given was sufficient to be able to answer the question  I couldn't say if there should have been more info.  As it is, I'm not likely to come back in the near future.  I don't want to be one of those people that slaps a "closed" or "insufficient" on a question prematurely.  Wouldn't mind reviewing "ignored" tags occasionally, just not always.

Comment: I've edited some questions that looked bad, they turned out to be good questions from non-native English speakers.  When I get feedback from the OP, I can help them write a good question.  That shows that some of the bad-spelling and grammar are not necessarily "bad question" indicators.  And the question lacked some rigour partly because the OP's mastery of English was not "perfect".  But with a little help, the questions turned out rigorous and useful.  It would be good to see a little more patience with non-native English speakers.  They struggle to use this great resource.

Answer (score 1):

So it's probably entirely possible to get 19 questions in a row that you really feel unqualified to triage, and rightfully so.  But I have a hard time imagining that this is a regular occurrence - and if you're finding it to be a regular occurrence, you might not be the right person to be triaging the general population of questions in the first place (which is what the triage queues are for).

In other words, if you're regularly experiencing that you cannot discern the quality of a question, and you could only discern it if it was tailored specifically to your area of interest, you probably aren't going to be able to help a whole lot on that review queue - and instead, you would be more productive just actively looking for questions in your preferred tags and respond/comment/edit them as appropriate (e.g. you know JavaScript really well and so you just browse the latest [javascript] questions and manually triage them).

Comment: While I agree, this approach notably lacks badge-ification.

Comment: There are badges for editing questions...  I think there might be badges for successful flags as well?

Comment: @DanField Yes, there's the [Citizen Patrol](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol), [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy), [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) series of badges

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that it doesn't follow the stream normally awarded for review tasks, but that's a good point.

Comment: My belief is the phenomenon is getting worse, and that it's not me-- either a change in the site, or a trend in questions asked.  My reason for saying that is that it was *not* happening a year or two ago when I started Triaging-- I was definitely *not* hitting Skip on so many back then.  I really am not that much of a specialist.  So my impression was the 19 out of 20 the other day was part of the trend I'd already been seeing, but you may be right that it's not a regular occurrance, I don't know.  I'll check again next time I get a batch of questions to Triage-- my queue is currently empty.