# Is it reasonable that I'm asked to triage/review posts on subjects I know nothing about?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, triage

I don't do a whole lot of reviewing work on Stack Overflow (I mostly answer, edit and comment). I was just checking out the triage queue and noticed I keep getting questions about PHP, Python, and WordPress.

Now, I barely know any Python or WordPress and know zero PHP. More concretely - I haven't answered questions about any of them, even (IIRC).

So why does it make sense to serve me questions about them? (And it's not as though they're also about abstract subjects in which I do have answers.)

(And yes, I realize I can *skip*. But I skip, skip skip and get more and more of them.)

Comment: Triaging (unlike other types of reviewing) should not require subject-matter expertise, so, yes, this is normal and reasonable. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297317/why-is-there-no-filter-in-triage-review, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393298/filter-the-triage-review-queue-by-subject-expertise, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288874/filtering-to-avoid-need-to-overuse-skip-in-triage-low-quality-posts-et-al, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364975/is-there-a-way-to-triage-without-spending-most-of-my-time-skipping-unfamiliar-te

Comment: If you are not sure what the correct option is just **skip the review.**

Comment: @SecurityHound They're aware of that, they even say *"(And yes, I realize I can Skip. But I skip, skip skip and get more and more of them.)"* - The question is, why show questions on which they may have no knowledge _at all_?

Comment: @Nick - How can an automatic system know what topics the author knows.  I know about tons of topics, never answered a question about them, and I can certainly tell the difference between a good question and bad question on topics I know nothing about

Comment: @SecurityHound Well it could look at tags you've answered/asked questions in for one example (questions you've proven yourself to have _some_ knowledge in), but it doesn't. And that's the point, because you don't need knowledge, I was just explaining how your comment *"just skip the review."* is unhelpful, OP knows that.

Comment: @SecurityHound In addition to the skip button, maybe we could have a "Skip all questions with [tag]" button.

Comment: This author might know it, but everyone who complains about their triage review suspensions don’t.  My comment is for those users.

Comment: Speaking as **the opposition** I will say, I have never up-voted a meta post, ... ever ... I gave you an up-vote.   On a personal note, I did reviews - ***once*** - in 2018, and eventually argued with @CodyGray about how silly it was, who subsequently closed my account, and theoretically I could 'triage' many things about **Java** (or **HTML**) - but I don't because closing people's "stupid questions" just makes me wonder what the purpose of any of this is...  OK.. "It's a stupid question that you have asked 50 times..."  So?  Closing it is wrong, ***and only instigates it further anyway..***

Comment: @SecurityHound: Can you clarify what you mean by "triage review suspensions"?

Comment: @Y2020-09: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I just asked about the choice of subjects about which I'm served questions to triage. You seem to be talking about other issues...?

Comment: I can't help but notice that CodyGray linked to some old posts about Triage. The problem here is that is seems users have been getting review suspensions for making mistakes in Triage as if they should have been making decisions as subject matter experts. So I'm not sure those are valid arguments.

Comment: @SecurityHound Compared to the other queues, the amount of posts that one has to Skip in the queue is ridiculously high due to not being able to filter posts. I assume you already well know that if you review even a small amount.

Comment: @einpoklum - Review suspensions caused by choosing the incorrect option while performing Triage reviews.

Comment: @Scratte - It doesn’t take a SME to determine if a question meets the minimum requirements for a question.

Comment: @einpklum Well, the subject of closing questions ***is germaine*** to who is doing the closing.  When a new "triage guy" (which, as I said, I was once... but never did it again) starts reviewing questions with languages he doesn't even know - it is only encouraging the telling of ***new Stack Overflow users*** that they aren't competent "question askers."  Having a giant infrastructure that encourages people to tell new users their questions are bad, ***rather than*** a system that encourages ***providing answers*** to questions is why people say ***Stack Overflow*** isn't a very nice place.

Comment: **TL;DR** Why would you ever close a **PHP Question** if you don't even know **PHP**?  Very often the problem is the little details you never thought about.

Comment: We're not toxic or callous @TheLeb, people just don't read instructions on how to write a good question. We're not here to help individuals, we're here to make a library of knowledge to help the greater population

Comment: "Why would you ever close a PHP Question if you don't even know PHP?" <- many reasons. No code while asking about why the code doesn't work; the English part of the question is unintelligible; a "can you write my program for me" question; request for a specific piece of software. But I better understand what you mean now.

Comment: @SecurityHound It takes one to determine that it's OK. And sometimes a post is closed because it looks like it's not OK. It would be really great do be able to filter posts there, so it wasn't such a skip-queue. If one can see a post needs information and one decides to not skip it, and then author adds it after the post is reviewed, then what?.. If one isn't an SME, they can't tell if it's OK. Retracting the flag is saying it is OK. Keeping the flag there is saying it's not OK. That's a pickle.

Comment: @Scratte - It absolutely does not take a SME to determine if a question can be edited by a community user.

Comment: @SecurityHound It absolutely *does* take an SME to see if a post has enough information be OK with an edit from someone else than author. How do you know if there's enough information or if the post is really a typo and should be closed if you're not familiar with the tag?

Comment: @Scratte - I personally perform basic research, if I can’t determine if the question contains enough information, I skip the review.  But I can tell if a question meets the minimum requirements for a question typically.

Comment: @SecurityHound Reviewing based on "meets the minimum requirements for a question" is likely to get one review suspended. One needs to be **sure** in that queue. I'm also not comfortable with the message that comment sends to new reviewers, as they are the most likely to fall into that trap of thinking they can tell if a Question is fine based on this metric. The best option is to have a filter, so one doesn't need to skip 10 to review one post, as I did.

Comment: I use that metric and I have never been suspended from performing a review.  I also clearly indicated I do basic research before choosing any option while performing a review.  We clearly won’t agree on this subject.  I have seen a ton of “I have been suspended from performing reviews”, and in nearly ever case, the review was about a question that didn’t meet the minimum requirements for a question.  Specifically, the question was so bad, nobody but the user could improve it.  In those cases, the users being suspended, choose “needs edit” nearly every time

Comment: I'm always inclined to check a profile for the "Reviewer" and the "Steward" badge when they say that they use a metric that for others usually results in review suspensions. "It absolutely does not take a SME to determine if a question can be edited by a community user." is exactly the "Needs community edit", which is the one users mostly get suspended for. I'm not sure what you're really trying to say.

Comment: From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/215552): "The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort potentially-problematic posts into categories that can be routed elsewhere." There *shouldn't* be a lot of in-depth thought put into it. Just get it in a bucket so that others can more closely look at the question. If you can't do that without domain knowledge to guide you, then you may be in the wrong review queue for your temperament. Feel guilty or bad about skipping so many questions? Ditto.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the Triage queue questions appear unrelated to the domain of expertise of the user seems **unreasonable** to me. I suggested a possible fix [elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402529/967621). I am reposting it below, adding a few substantial improvements and changes.

**The Triage queue should show more questions related to the "watched tags" of the reviewer. Alternatively, the Triage queue should show more questions with tags that are related to the tags appearing in the threads of the reviewer (questions, answers and comments by the reviewer).**

Related tags are determined by their frequency of co-occurrence within the same question across the entire Stack Overflow. Using this definition, [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) are more related than, for example, [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).

I understand that we want to triage **all** questions regardless of whether they have tags that are watched by the users. But the queue should not be **entirely** random. Instead, the Triage queue should be **enriched** up to a certain percent (between 0 and 100%, the optimum can be determined experimentally) by the questions with the watched or related tags.

Spiking in non-random questions into the Triage queue is not a novel idea. You occasionally get "test" questions designed to check "if you are paying attention" anyway under the current system. I simply suggest another type of spike-in questions - the "more related" type of questions. This would result in more meaningful reviews and less "skip, skip, skip" type of behavior.

**SEE ALSO:**

Something similar has been suggested many times before, see below. But the previous OPs asked mostly about using plain filters based on tags (which would limit the Triage queue to 100% watched tags, or something similar). **I suggest a level of spike-in less than 100%, so that rarely watched tags or untagged questions get enough reviews as well.**

[Filter the Triage review queue by subject/expertise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393298/967621)
[Why is there no filter in triage review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297317/967621)
[I only want to see items related to my favorite tags in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285413/967621)
[Review triage questions accordingly to my favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280773/967621)

Comment: You're not being asked to assess the question content but the structure, is it clearly defined?, does the title make sense?, if it's a debugging problem has at least some code been included? None of this requires domain knowledge of the subject matter, just a bit if common sense.

Comment: @Lankymart I think we should try to optimize the rate of reviews and the accuracy of reviews in the Triage queue. Clearly the OP and I both reduce our rate and/or accuracy under the current system. I suggest one possible way to optimize the system.

Comment: By allowing people to review their watched tags you end up watering down the review process. Resulting in tags with high traffic seeing more reviews completed while low traffic tags will be left to stagnate in the review queue mire.

Comment: @Lankymart I think that we should optimize the rate and accuracy of the reviews of all tags. I simply suggested to spike in the user-related tags. The spike in percent can be pretty low, most likely a lot less than 100%. Also I suggested to use related tags, not necessarily the watched tags. That’s a much broader selection of questions.

Comment: Favourite, related the result is the same, you water down the review pool.

Comment: @Lankymart I think that to resolve the difference in our views, SO should do experiments to optimIze the metrics that they care the most about. I could be wrong, but it may be that the optimal % of user related questions spike in could be not the current 0% but somewhere around 5-50%. Let the data guide our decisions!

Answer (score 4):

While you don't have perhaps the domain knowledge to *answer* the question, you do have the community knowledge to tell if the question is properly written.

It should be easy to tell questions that have formatting issues, have no code, are spam or blatant off-topic.

The problem goes for those questions that are, theoretically, properly written, but may lack some details that you're not aware of due to your lack of knowledge in the framework. For example, let's assume you have no idea on Docker, a user posted a `docker-compose.yml` file but no `Dockerfile`. You can't tell that file is required for Docker, because you don't know that fact.

So yes, you should skip those questions if they apparently seem well-written, and let users more knowledgeable tell if the question needs more detail.

Is it bad that SO gives you questions like that in triage? not necessarily. Maybe you cannot complete triage on questions out of your knowledge, but you are still able to quickly turn out the spam and very low quality content. Giving you these questions reduce the time a low quality post needs to be removed (since it reaches a broader audience), perhaps at the expense that some better detailed post missing details take a bit longer to close. That's OK to me, we're tackling down the most problematic questions first.

If a post without key details but well-written survives 30 minutes, maybe some people will already tell the author the missing details and flag the post anyway without it being in the triage. But a spam or malware post surviving 30 minutes is way more critical for the community.

Comment: But wouldn't it be better to direct questions to more-domain-knowledgeable people rather than uniformly? ... unless there's queue overflow (pun not intended) on some of the tags, I mean. Fair point regarding spam and blatant off-topics - although I've never gotten one of those yet to triage.

Comment: @einpoklum No, because simply put, there isn't enough reviewers and by filtering the reviewers by their favorite tags you just end up watering it down further.